# View all scheduled tasks that have a specific state

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm using Org-mode 8.2.10 on Xubuntu 16.04 and despite having tried many combinations, I can't manage to view **all** scheduled tasks that don't have "DONE" and "CANCELLED" as a state. For example,

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(
     ("+" "Scheduled" 
       ((todo ""
         ((org-agenda-overriding-header "\nScheduled")
          (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notscheduled 'todo '("DONE" "CANCELLED")))
         )
       ))
     )
   )
)
```

shows all scheduled tasks but including (instead of excluding) those with "DONE" and "CANCELLED" states...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be a bug in the function `org-agenda-skip-if`.  Here's the source code, with irrelevant portions snipped out by `[...]`:

```
(defun org-agenda-skip-if (subtree conditions)
  (let (beg end m)
    (org-back-to-heading t)
    (setq beg (point)
          end [...])
    (goto-char beg)
    (and
     (or
      (and (memq 'scheduled conditions)
           (re-search-forward org-scheduled-time-regexp end t))
      (and (memq 'notscheduled conditions)
           (not (re-search-forward org-scheduled-time-regexp end t)))
      [...]
      (and (or [...]
            (setq m (memq 'todo conditions)))
           (org-agenda-skip-if-todo m end)))
     end)))
```

The idea seems to be that each clause under the outer `or` calls `re-search-forward` to skip things matching a regex appropriate to that clause.  If the search doesn't find anything, then `re-search-forward` returns nil, and the function checks the next clause.  (The subroutine `org-agenda-skip-if-todo` does the same thing inside that last clause.)  Presumably the function as a whole is called inside a `save-excursion` so that things that shouldn't be skipped aren't; the value returned on a skip (`end`) is pre-computed, so the function doesn't pay attention to where it's leaving point.

The problem is that `not` form wrapping `re-search-forward` under the `notscheduled` clause.  That just means that the function keeps going, but `re-search-forward` has already moved point past anything that might be found by the later `re-search-forward` inside `org-agenda-skip-if-todo`.

The quick and (very) dirty solution, therefore, is to redefine `org-agenda-skip-if` with a version wrapping that `re-search-forward` form inside its own `save-excursion`.

EDIT: Here's a less dirty solution using advice and [noflet](https://github.com/nicferrier/emacs-noflet):

```
(defun patch/org-agenda-skip-if (oldfun subtree conditions)
  "Advice patching the \"bad negation\" bug in `org-agenda-skip-if'.

The function `org-agenda-skip-if' does not behave correctly when
given multiple conditions, at least one of which is a
negative (e.g., `notscheduled' or `nottodo').  This function
corrects the problem when applied as :around advice."
  (let ((use-excursion t))
    (noflet ((re-search-forward (&rest args)
                                (if use-excursion
                                    (save-excursion (apply this-fn args))
                                  (apply this-fn args)))
             (outline-next-heading (&rest args)
                                   (let ((use-excursion nil)) (apply this-fn args))))
      (funcall oldfun subtree conditions))))

(advice-add 'org-agenda-skip-if :around #'patch/org-agenda-skip-if)
```

---

Alternatively, for your particular case, you might consider just labeling both `DONE` and `CANCELLED` as "done" keywords.  If you do that, then they'll be skipped by default, and you can drop that second clause from the skip function:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("+" "Scheduled" 
         ((todo
           ""
           ((org-agenda-overriding-header "\nScheduled")
            (org-agenda-skip-function
             '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notscheduled))))))))
```

Comment: Many thanks Aaron! I followed your last advice, by adding a "|" in my todo-keywords:   `(setq org-todo-keywords '((type "TODO" "NEXT" "STARTED" "WAITING" "FROZEN" "REFERENCE" "DELEGATED" "|" "CANCELLED" "DONE")))`